# Given an SHA code from GitHub, how can I replace a package with pip install?

Tags: python, github, pip, sha

**Edit:** Instead of the SHA code, a separate, more standard, method from the comments is being used

I've tried

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/hramezani/urllib3.git@6a77aa11fe849f988c07b53e1d31d082de07a2e3 --user`

but I get "ERROR: Could not build wheels for urllib3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Comment: Why is the SHA code involved here? Use [PATs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to link github to the command line.

Comment: It just appeared like an easy copy/paste solution. Looking into the link.

Comment: you can also use a url like `https://username:password@mygithost.com/my/repository` to avoid linking github to the command line but it is pretty insecure as it shows your password.

Comment: @Allie I think the issue might be with my usage of pip, though

Comment: Ah yes, I see now it's a public repo. Make sure to `pip3 install --upgrade pip3` and `pip3 install --upgrade wheel`. Other than that seems like a fairly standard use of pip. I just tried `pip3 install git+https://github.com/hramezani/urllib3.git` and it worked fine.

Comment: @Allie Yes, all of that made it work.